# turtles are not moving through the door

Tags: netlogo

[image]Here is my code. I have walls in the colors grey and brown, which turtles should avoid when moving. I have to move my turtles when Eat = 1 toward the door with the color green and enter the room if Eat =0 turtle has to move in black patches only.
I have an issue as turtles are not moving through the door and also when facing the wall they stop there instead of

```
  to go
      
        ask students  [
pd
set heading 90
 forward 1
if (eat = 1)
      [
        if (([pcolor] of patch-left-and-ahead 90 1 = green) or ([pcolor] of patch-left-and-ahead 90 2 = green) or 
          ([pcolor] of patch-left-and-ahead 90 3 = green) or ([pcolor] of patch-left-and-ahead 90 4 = green) or
          ([pcolor] of patch-left-and-ahead 90 5 = green) and pycor <= -10 )
        [ 
          set heading towards one-of patches with [pcolor = green]
          forward 1
        ]
          if ([pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = green)
        [
          set heading 0
          forward 3
        ]
      
        if (pycor >= -9 and [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = black)
      [
          set heading 270
          forward 1
        ] 
        
      ]

while [ any? patches in-radius 1 with [ pcolor = grey ] or any? patches in-radius 1 with [ pcolor = brown - 2]] [
bk 1
lt (random 180) - 90
fd 1
 ]
 ]

  tick
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks quite chaotic to me so it is hard to give immediate pointers. Instead, let me describe what happens at each part:

```
let new-patch patch-ahead 2
```

You define new-patch as the patch in the direction your student is currently facing

```
if ([pcolor] of patch-here = black ) [
  ifelse (eat = 0)
  [set heading random 360
    forward 1]
  [         
    set heading random 360
    forward 1
    set heading towards one-of patches with [pcolor = green]
    forward 5
  ]
```

When a turtle is standing on a black patch, it has two options, depending on whether or not it has any eat. If it has no eat, it faces a random direction and takes a step forward. If it has eat, it also faces a random direction and takes a step forward. After that it chooses a random door and moves 5 steps towards it.

The immediate problems I see with this part are:

- What is the purpose of turning in a completely random direction and stepping forward?
- Since both the turtles with eat and those without eat have the random walk it, it should not be inside the `ifelse` blocks.
- The random step could make your turtle step onto a grey or brown patch, which I assume you don't want
- The students with `eat != 1` move towards a random green patch but this green patch they choose can be a different one each tick, causing them to move back and forward between two doors. I suggest either having them pick one door as destination and storing it as a turtle variable, always moving towards that one until they reach it (`set my-door one-of patches with [pcolor = green]`) or having them move towards the closest door (`set heading towards min-one-of (patches with [pcolor = green]) [distance myself]`)
- Here as well, your turtle could walk onto a wall if it is in the direct line towards your door

Onto the next part

```
if ([pcolor] of new-patch = grey or [pcolor] of new-patch = brown - 2 ) [
  right 180
  forward 1
]
```

Here you have the turtle turn around and take a step in the other direction, if the patch that was 2 in front of them at the start was grey or brown.

- This part of the code is executed regardless of whether or not the first part was executed, meaning that if the turtle stood on a black patch before, it first chose `new-patch` as the patch that was 2 in front of it, then it did some random turning and a step forward, and now it checks what color the patch they initially defined as `new-patch` had, even if they are now looking in a completely opposite direction. This could actually make them turn back towards the patch you are trying to avoid
- I'm just wondering, why have `new-patch` be the patch that is 2 steps ahead and not 1 step ahead?

And finally

```
  if ( pxcor >= -9 and [pcolor] of patch-here = grey or [pcolor] of patch-here = brown - 2)[
           left 180
           forward 1
]
```

Here you have a turtle turn around if the patch they are standing on is grey or brown. Not necessarily a bad way of solving them walking into walls but it does not solve all of those instances and furthermove provides problems once you are stuck in those walls

Let's assume you are standing on a grey patch while facing the door. This means that there is generally grey in front and grey behind. Since the student is not standing on black, there is no random walk. The patch 2 ahead is grey so you turn around and take a step. Now you are standing on another grey patch so you turn back and take a step, ending right where you started this tick.
Of course for this to happen you first need to actually end up in the wall. For that we have the `forward 5` from earlier to blame. A turtle that is close to the wall and moves 5 steps toward a door can do so through part of a wall. It gets deep enough for both of your 180° turns not to be able to get them out.

Instead of all this turning around, I suggest you add in a local variable called destination `let destination patch-ahead 1`, let it check whether or not that patch is a wall and only start randomly turning if it is a wall. Then `set destination patch-ahead 1` and check again. Only let it move towards destination after all the checking is done.

In general, I suggest you let the turtles put their pen down to more accurately trace their movement `ask turtles [pd]`, reduce the number of turtles and see what happens from step to step

As to your final question of why they don't move through the door: well, in the code there is no command that tells them what to do if the patch they are standing on is green so once they step onto the green they will simply stop. (or if they manage to move through the door, they will turn back towards it (or another door) and with the random walks added in, they will eventually end up either in a wall or on top of the door, both of which make them stop)

Last but certainly not least: start a bit smaller. Use just one or a few turtles, a short wall and a single door. Make sure your movement works on that before scaling up to all those different rooms

I hope this points you in the right direction and will be glad to further elaborate if you have questions

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations and suggestions. I did follow your suggestions and updated my code but I still face some issues in avoiding walls. I updated the code and screenshot which I am getting above. Please check and let me know where else am I going wrong.

Comment: Hey there, I didn't really have much time the past few days. Since you opened a new question, I'll take a look at it over there